# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

I have just downloaded the wamp server. I want to establish a connection to MySQL database with PHP and I'm using the root user, localhost and the name of my database. My code seems to be correct but when I run it on wamp, I get the following error:
Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\wamp\www\cone.php on line 8
and
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Also, the error message that I haven't been connected to the database(from my if statement) is displayed.

Does this mean that I have to do some extra configuration on the server?

Here is my code:

`<?php`

`$dbcon = mysqli_connect('root','', 'localhost', 'people');`

```
`if(!$dbcon)` 
`{`
    `die('error connecting to database');`
`}`
`echo "success";`
```

`?>`

Thank you in advance

Comment: is the wampserver service active in the background ?

Comment: Yes, I checked all the components of it and they are started

Comment: just noticed that the parameters isn't correct. Raymond's answer is the right one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo (switched arguments)

Comment: It's from my first attempts to do that, so I'm sorry for the mess. Yeah, Raymond's answer was right, but now I have issue with this error:Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\wamp\www\cone.php on line 3. This is relevant to my password on mysql I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysqli_connect('root','', 'localhost', 'people');
```

You are passing root in as hostname.

try this

```
mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '', 'people');
```

this will connect to localhost with username root  passwoord "" and default database people.

maybe better to change localhost with 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks! That took care of it. Now I get another error though: Warning: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\wamp\www\cone.php on line 3. Is this something relevant with my password on MySQL?

Comment: mysqli_connect('localhost','root', NULL, 'people');

Comment: Should be mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '', 'people');

Comment: could you please tell location of this file?. I am using Drupal 7