# making a mySQL database from form data

Tags: mysql, sql, forms, csv

I am trying to create a mySQL database using form data (using WYSIWYG wb9). It successfully updates a .csv file with new data, but the phpmyadmin made sql database doesn´t get updated (which I want to make query searches). How do I link this to form data?

Maybe my ONE.com account will not let me, but it states this service is functional when you buy the domain. Or am I missing some php code to get this to work. I'm starting to go round in circles, hence my question here.

Any advice welcome.

Comment: After form submission I get a page stating:                        Failed to connect to database server!
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Comment: What code are you using now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are using the root as your hostname..I think its what the error shows.

Check the links here

[Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161731/warning-mysqli-connect-hy000-2002-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-f)

[mysql_connect: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known using file values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876269/mysql-connect-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-no-such-host-is-kno)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out. Just worried that I am running before I can walk with making a webpage. Does the data auto-link to a mySQL database, or do I need to correct column values to match variable code?

Comment: you need to do it manually ..see the link ..and acccept the answer if it helped ..:)